# Java code implement OWLAnnotationPropertyAssertionAxiom

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, owl-api, turtle-rdf

I want to add annotation assertion on a triple. I tried doing the same using Protege and was able to achieve it. The RDF/XMl generated from the Protege looks like this:

```
<owl:Axiom>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/smrat/ontologies/2019/0/untitled-ontology-1388#Peter"/>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/smrat/ontologies/2019/0/untitled-ontology-1388#eats"/>
        <owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/smrat/ontologies/2019/0/untitled-ontology-1388#Apple"/>
        <weight rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">3</weight>
    </owl:Axiom>
```

I want to achieve the same using owldistribution-api. If anyone hasdone done would appreciate help!
Thank you!

Comment: Use `OWLDataFactory#getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(OWLObjectPropertyExpression, OWLIndividual, OWLIndividual, Collection<OWLAnnotation>)`

Comment: Thank you! Is there any sample code for the same? I am not sure how to use Collection<OWLAnnotation> .

Comment: To produce annotation use `OWLDataFactory#getOWLAnnotation(OWLAnnotationProperty, OWLAnnotationValue)`